# How to select a CC replacement led driver?

Tags: led-driver

I have a led ramp in my bathroom. It's dead. The led driver isn't providing any volts on it's output side.

The previous driver was an EBIR AED06-700IIP44 but I can't find a new one.
It's a constant current 700mA IP44 led driver that supply up to 13V and 6W.

I'm not at ease with cc stuff and I can't find another brand with the same characteristics.

==> **Except for the mandatory "700mA cc", what should I focus on ? 6W ? 13V max ? both ? or it doesn't matter ?**

At amazon I found a Goobay 30602 LED driver cc 700 mA/Class II/17V max/12 W Max.
Could it be a good replacement part ?

Comment: At least 6 W and at least 13 V if you used the previous one to its full potential. Be aware that compliance voltage is usually a range and not just max.

Comment: I recommend buying a replacement driver from a reputable company and not the cheapest generic part you can find on ebay or amazon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an led driver that can provide 700mA at 13V.
Constant current drivers typically have a voltage range in which they can provide the specified current (often refered to as "constant current region"). That's like with a CV power supply, which has a specific current range in which it can provide the nominal voltage. While the rated current for a CV psu typically starts a 0A, led drivers often operate only above a minimum output voltage. If you don't want to dim(-to-off) the leds, it is only important to have a driver with the rated current and a max operating voltage *above* the leds' voltage rating.

If you want to dim the leds to off, additionally the driver's minimum output voltage has to be below the leds' threshold voltage.

The Goobay 30602 LED driver you propse appears to work at a minimum *power* of 0.5W while providing no more than 700mA, so this driver should be suitable for your leds.